# Combat Challenge vs Opportunity Attack - which happens first?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, opportunity-attack, mark

If a fighter has marked an enemy, and the enemy does a ranged attack against someone other than the fighter, I believe the fighter can attack using `Combat Challenge` as the enemy is making an attack which does not target the fighter, and also an `Opportunity Attack` as the enemy is making a ranged attack.

So which attack happens first ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can do them in either order**, both are effectively interrupts.

The Combat Challenge is an `Immediate Interrupt` while the Opportunity attack is (obviously) an `Opportunity Attack`.

After the first attack is done, the fighter will need to recheck to validate that the Opportunity Attack is still valid.  For example, the Combat Challenge might push the enemy so that it is no longer adjacent to the fighter and then the Opportunity action would be lost.

This is all assuming that:

- The fighter is adjacent to the enemy making the ranged attack
- The fighter has the enemy marked
- The enemy is not attacking the fighter
- The fighter has not spent his Immediate Action since the end of his last turn.
- The fighter has not used an Opportunity Action during this enemies turn.

Comment: Yeah that was my conclusion ... thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding from what I've seen on here, the fighter only gets to make one attack, not both.  The reason being that, when it's not your turn, you only get one action per other character's turn.  I am probably wrong though.

Comment: You get one interrupt per round, but one opportunity action per turn